# Send mail by amazon ses with Arabic sender name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon SES to send mail message to web users and I want to set the sender name in Arabic as below:

```
Dim mailObj As New SendEmailRequest
mailObj.Source = "تطبيق كتابى <mymail@mydomain.com>"
```

The mail successfully sent but the sender name is shown in wrong way as below:

```
*7(JB C*'(I mymail@mydomain.com
```

What should I do to view the sender name as configured?

Comment: sounds like a `Culture setting` to me.. investigate how to use `CultureInfo` perhaps

Comment: nothing happens the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the majority of mail servers, including Amazon SES.

The problem is that the original specification ([RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)) defines email addresses to consist of ASCII characters only. A recent specification ([RFC-6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531)) seeks to extend that specification to include support for Unicode characters in email addresses, but support for this in existing infrastructure is very poor.

UPDATE: I did find this specification ([RFC-2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)) that is an extension to support a special encoding of international characters in an e-mail address, and it looks like Amazon [supports it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Destination.html). You'll have some programming to do, however, because I don't know how to encoding works.