# Latin characters in Amazon SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

In my Rails application, I am using [AWS-SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) to send emails through SES via SMTP. Here are how SMTP settings look like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  :domain               => "my-domain.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  :password             => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Things work fine, until I have to send emails to addresses with Latin/Greek characters (ex. `utşav@my-domain.com`). In this case, I get following error: `Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided`.

I tried looking at [Special Characters in Amazon SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876157/special-characters-in-amazon-ses) but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> International characters above U+007F, encoded as UTF-8, are permitted by RFC 6531, though mail systems may restrict which characters to use when assigning local parts.
>
> — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part

That said, `Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided` is likely returned by your SMTP provider, who just rejects this addresses, being not so tolerant to fashionable RFCs.

Is there any setting to be turned on on Amazon?

*UPD*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20214811/2035262